# Is there a way to stop repeated Jenkins failure notifications being sent to slack or email?

Tags: jenkins, notifications, jenkins-pipeline

There are a few flaky automation tests in our project and at times they fail due to either timeout or some other issues but I have noticed that it returns back to normal on its own, so in the `Jenkinsfile` script is there a way so that the slack channel doesn't keep getting the build failures notifications after maybe 2-3 failures and then just send the notification when the build returns to normal/SUCCESS state?

I was thinking of including a different stage for success and failure and iterate over them? Not sure if that would work or if it's the correct approach for it.

````
    try {
        stage('Run Smoke Tests') {
            #Test Workers setup & called here
        }
        echo "BUILD SUCCESS"
        stage('Publish Slack Notification') {

            slackSend color: '#2ECC71', channel: slackChannel, message: " Production Smoke Tests - Passed! :awesome: \n" +
                    " List of Enabled Tests : ${Link} \n" +
                    " Jenkins Test Result : ${jenkinsTestReport}"
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        echo "BUILD FAILURE"
        slackSend color: '#FF0000', channel: slackChannel, message: " Production Smoke Tests - Failed! :sadpanda: \n" +
                " List of Enabled Tests : ${Link} \n" +
                " Jenkins Test Report : ${jenkinsTestReport}"
        throw err
    }
    finally {
        cleanWs()
    }
}```
````